# Linux C++ Network Session monitor

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, proc, netlink

I'm trying to monitor the network sessions on server withe event driven programming (and not polling on `/proc/net/tcp` or `udp`).

I was able to find [this article](http://kristrev.github.io/2013/07/26/passive-monitoring-of-sockets-on-linux/) but it only provide one time look at the current state and not an event on each change (LISTEN, ESTABLISHED...).

Is it possible to use this like in [this article](http://netsplit.com/the-proc-connector-and-socket-filters) that monitors processes changes but on network connections?

If not, is there any other API that I can use in order to achive this without polling `/porc/net/*` in interval?